# C++ Objective AlgLib

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have an c++ code. that i have to use in objective c.

```
double[,] x = new double[,]{{-1},{-0.8},{-0.6},{-0.4},{-0.2},{0},{0.2},{0.4},{0.6},{0.8},{1.0}};
double[] y = new double[]{0.223130,0.382893,0.582748,0.786628,0.941765,1.000000,0.941765,0.786628,0.582748,0.382893,0.223130};
double[] c = new double[]{0.3};

double epsf = 0;
double epsx = 0.000001;

int maxits = 0;
int info;

alglib::lsfitstate state;
alglib::lsfitreport rep;

double diffstep = 0.0001;    

//
// Fitting with weights
// (you can change weights and see how it changes result)
//

double[] w = new double[]{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

alglib::lsfitcreatewf(x, y, w, c, diffstep, out state);
alglib::lsfitsetcond(state, epsf, epsx, maxits);
alglib::lsfitfit(state, function_cx_1_func, null, null);
alglib::lsfitresults(state, out info, out c, out rep);
```

i already called my objective file at the end with .mm

But i get difference Errors. (first lines - expected expression when i init my vars).

I can't [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). But i only need this one function.

I hope that this is a solution for this question.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74567/math-algorithm-for-n-amount-points-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is mostly Java code at the beginning for the array declarations, not C, C++ or ObjC.

This would be C/C++ code:

```
double x[][1] = {{-1},{-0.8},{-0.6},{-0.4},{-0.2},{0},{0.2},{0.4},{0.6},{0.8},{1.0}};
double y[] = {0.223130,0.382893,0.582748,0.786628,0.941765,1.000000,0.941765,0.786628,0.582748,0.382893,0.223130};
double c[] = {0.3};
```

However, according to the `lsfitcreatewf` function reference [here](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#sub_lsfitcreatewf), you need it to be of the type `alglib::real_2d_array`. There are some examples [here](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#gs_vecmat) how to generate such data.

[Here](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#example_lsfit_d_lin) and following are some general examples about how to use the lsfit subpackage.

Comment: Hey Thank you. Hmm now i understand the problem. The example was in C#. Im looking for an Example in C++. Do you know some examples od did you ever use this function (Lib)?

Comment: No, I haven't. But you'll find examples on the page I linked. I extended my answer.